# Numpy - IF element is less than or equal to, then pass

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to sort through a list of values in NUMPY / UPROOT, and I am having trouble with the formatting, as I am new to UPROOT.

The values are in some other list, and we'll call the values in one by one with a name, x.

If the values of x is greater than or equal to 5, I want to add it to the array, which is initially empty. If the number is less than 5, then we move onto the next number.

specifically, I need help with how to format the "greater than equal to"

```
array = [] 

if x is greater than or equal to 5:
    array.append(x)
else:
    return 0
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: As a suggestion, if you're going to be appending to a collection, use Python lists, not NumPy arrays. The `array.append` method has to copy everything every time it appends because arrays can't grow in length. Python lists are intended for this kind of access.

Answer (score 2):

Using numpy you can do something like:

```
import numpy as np

# Initialize array
array = np.array([])
  
# Make some random values for x  
x = np.floor(np.random.rand(10)*10)
  
for i in x: # Loop through x
    if i >= 5: # If value is bigger or equal to 5
        array = np.append(array, i) # add to array
```

So, "greater than equal to" is just `>=`

Answer (score 0):

you're using a python list, which is different from numpy arrays. either way the following code should work

```
X = np.random.random(size= [10])    # array containing x values
```

if you want an numpy array

```
arr = X[X >= 5]
```

if you want a list

```
arr = list(X[X >= 5])
```